# Creating A Directory in an App on an iOS Device

Tags: objective-c, directory

In using this code in attempt to create a new directory on my iOS device, I get no errors or warnings, but no directory appears in my device's "File Sharing" tab on iTunes. Am I not creating the directory in the correct pathway? If so, how do I determine where to create the directory? Thank you, let me know if any clarifications are needed.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *directory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@.log", date];

NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
    // An error has occurred, do something to handle it
    NSLog(@"Failed to create directory \"%@\". Error: %@", directory, error);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code ir right, only you need one additional step:

```
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString documentsDirectory = paths.firstObject;
```

This code, search for physical path to sandbox's document path.

Adding this code, you have:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString documentsDirectory = paths.firstObject;

NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *directory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.log", date]];

NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]) {
    // An error has occurred, do something to handle it
    NSLog(@"Failed to create directory \"%@\". Error: %@", directory, error);
}
```

I hope help you!!